# Is there a Google Closure Compiler plugin for Notepad++

Tags: javascript, notepad++, google-closure-compiler

I looked around on "the Internet" but could not find a proper answer:

Is there a **[Google Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/closure/compiler/)** plugin for **[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)** or a way to get it working with *NppExec.Execute* (F6-key).

Comment: do you want the current file beeing replaced by the output of closure or should it be a different file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

go and grab http://closure-compiler.googlecode.com/files/compiler-latest.zip, then unzip it.
launch

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH) \
    --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS \
    --js_output_file $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART)-compiled.js
```

which creates a new file which is named as the currently used one but has `-compiled.js` at its end.

Comment: And how do I launch that from notepad++ ? ;) /noob

Comment: i am installing notepad++ just right now, just for you. beeing a vim-only dude .. this is a big favour :) http://superuser.com/questions/176678/how-to-launch-a-program-from-notepad that might help

Comment: Got it working... (there seems to be a small delay on win7 to detect if a file has changed, so I did not see any output) used: `java -jar compiler.jar --js $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)  --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --js_output_file $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART)-compiled.js`

Answer (score 1):

JSMinNpp plugin will minimize js code. It can be an alternative.

Have a try: http://jsminnpp.sf.net